# nginx unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line

Tags: nginx

I have a docker container running a nginx server and it is restarting again and again. Here are its logs:

```
docker logs frontend_matangi
2022/06/20 17:55:26 [emerg] 7#7: unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line
nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line
2022/06/20 17:55:28 [emerg] 7#7: unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line
nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line
2022/06/20 17:55:29 [emerg] 7#7: unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line
nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line
2022/06/20 17:55:30 [emerg] 7#7: unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line
nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line
2022/06/20 17:55:32 [emerg] 7#7: unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line
nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line
2022/06/20 17:55:34 [emerg] 7#7: unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line
nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line
```

However, I dont find any missing `;` in my /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf...
The default .conf file is removed during the docker build (rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf)

This is my nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name matangi.dev; 
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/build;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://171.20.128.2:8001/api;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size 20M;

        }
    location /wagtail {
        proxy_pass http://171.20.128.2:8001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /wagtail;
        client_max_body_size 20M;

        }

    location /djangostatic {
        alias /app/static;
        }       

    location /media {
        alias /app/media;
    }
}





server{
                  listen 443 ssl http2;
                  server_name matangi.dev;
                  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/matangi.dev/fullchain.pem; 
                  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/matangi.dev/privkey.pem;
                  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/matangi.dev/chain.pem;
                  include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
                }
```

There is no missing `;` in my letsencrypt.conf either :

```
location ^~/.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
allow all;
root /var/lib/letsencrypt/;
default_type "text/plain";
try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Comment: The error is about your command line parameter, not your config.
I'm running into the same issue now.

In my dockerfile I use `CMD nginx -g "daemon off;"` to overwrite the default JSON notation of the main NGINX dockerfile.
This is because the Jelastic platform that runs our container can't handle the JSON notation.

But now it suddenly started complaining about the CMD parameters.

Comment: @WillemBurgers and how did you manage it?

Comment: @SimonH in our case it was due to an update of the Jelastic platform. We had some conversations back and forth with the provider that runs Jelastic. I'm not sure if this got resolved at all or if we just put the daemon off part inside the config instead of the CMD parameters.